# Usuarios Sin registros en BD

Tags: mysql

Tengo 2 tablas, una de usuarios con `id` autoincrement

```
ID_usuario|nombre
```

y otra donde se registran sus accesos.

```
ID_acesso|ID_usuario|fecha_hora_registro
```

cómo puedo obtener los usuarios que no tengan ningun registro durante los 3 dias atras a partir de la fecha de consulta en la base de datos?

es decir, hoy es 18 de abril entonces que muestre los usuarios que no muestren registros a partir del 15 de abril

hola, de ante mano muchas gracias por tu ayuda
tengo esta consulta

```
SELECT
    (
    CASE
        WHEN (SELECT date_format(checkin.fecha_check_in,"%Y-%m-%d") FROM checkin WHERE checkin.usuario_id = 1080  ORDER BY checkin.fecha_check_in DESC LIMIT 1) <= DATE(timestamp(DATE_SUB( NOW() , INTERVAL 96 HOUR ) )) THEN (SELECT date_format(checkin.fecha_check_in,"%Y-%m-%d") FROM checkin WHERE checkin.usuario_id = 1080  ORDER BY checkin.fecha_check_in DESC LIMIT 1)
        WHEN (SELECT date_format(checkin.fecha_check_in,"%Y-%m-%d") FROM checkin WHERE checkin.usuario_id = 1080  ORDER BY checkin.fecha_check_in DESC LIMIT 1) >= DATE(timestamp(DATE_SUB( NOW() , INTERVAL 96 HOUR ) )) THEN 1
        WHEN (SELECT date_format(checkin.fecha_check_in,"%Y-%m-%d") FROM checkin WHERE checkin.usuario_id = 1080  ORDER BY checkin.fecha_check_in DESC LIMIT 1) IS NULL THEN 0
    END) AS last_check
```

el problema es que la ejecuto una vez por cada id que tengo

Comment: Qué has intentado hasta ahora para obtener esa información? Qué error encontraste al usar tu código?

Comment: Si añades código, edita la pregunta y pega el código allí. Es mucho más fácil que verlo por acá en los comentarios :)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes obtener el resultado de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT * 
FROM usuario
WHERE id NOT IN(
  SELECT usuario_id
  FROM checkin
  WHERE fecha_check_in >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY )
);
```